# Normalization of a curve using blow up

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I'm trying to solve exercise I.A-10 from *Geometry of algebraic curves* by E. Arbarello and others. I have to prove that the curve given by $\gamma:x^2+y^2+x^2 y^2=0$ is rational using the Riemann-Hurwitz formula on the $x$-axis projection $\pi_x:\gamma\rightarrow\mathbb{P}^1$ and looking for an explicit parametrization. The hint for the parametrization is to look at the conics through the three nodal points of the normalization of $\gamma$.
I have blown up at the singular point $(0,0)$ getting $\bar{\gamma}:x^2+x^2y^2+1=0$. My problems are:

1. I don't know how count moltiplicity of points at infinity of $\gamma$. Do I have to consider all them as preimages of $\infty\in\mathbb{P}^1$;
2. I can't find nodal points on $\bar{\gamma}$, is my normalization wrong?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: To compute the multiplicity at infinity, first homogenize to obtain $x^2z^2 + y^2z^2 + x^2y^2 = 0$, then intersect with the line at infinity $z=0$ to obtain $x^2y^2 = 0$. So you have double points at $(0:1:0)$ and $(1:0:0)$. I think what they want you to do is look at the conics through these points (and the one you found, $(0:0:1)$) to obtain a $2$-parameter family of conics that cuts out a linear system of degree $2$ on $\gamma$, and then pull this linear system back to the normalization.

Comment: I'm trying even if the Hessian of $\gamma$ is not singular at that point...
I've set the conics as $xy+Byz+Czx=0$ but I can't find anything rational :(